# POSIX rlimit: What exactly can we assume about RLIMIT_DATA?

Tags: memory, posix, setrlimit

### Prequisites

[POSIX.1 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) [specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setrlimit.html) the `setrlimit()` and `getrlimit()` functions. Various constants are provided for the *`resource`* argument, some of which are reproduced below for easier understaning of my question.

> The following resources are defined:
>
> (...)
>
> #### RLIMIT_DATA
>
> This is the maximum size of a data segment of the process, in bytes. If this limit is exceeded, the malloc() function shall fail with errno set to [ENOMEM].
>
> (...)
>
> #### RLIMIT_STACK
>
> This is the maximum size of the initial thread's stack, in bytes. The implementation does not automatically grow the stack beyond this limit. If this limit is exceeded, SIGSEGV shall be generated for the thread. If the thread is blocking SIGSEGV, or the process is ignoring or catching SIGSEGV and has not made arrangements to use an alternate stack, the disposition of SIGSEGV shall be set to SIG_DFL before it is generated.
>
> #### RLIMIT_AS
>
> This is the maximum size of total available memory of the process, in bytes. If this limit is exceeded, the malloc() and mmap() functions shall fail with errno set to [ENOMEM]. In addition, the automatic stack growth fails with the effects outlined above.

Furthermore, POSIX.1 2008 [defines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_125) *data segment* like this:

> #### 3.125 Data Segment
>
> Memory associated with a process, that can contain dynamically allocated data.

I understand that the `RLMIT_DATA` resource was traditionally used to denote the maximum amount of memory that can be assigned to a process with the `brk()` function. Recent editions of POSIX.1 do no longer specify this function and many operating systems (e.g. Mac OS X) do not support this function as a system call. Instead it is emulated with a variant of `mmap()` which is not part of POSIX.1 2008.

### Questions

I am a little bit confused about the semantic and use of the `RLIMIT_DATA` resource. Here are the concrete questions I have:

- Can the stack be part of the data segment according to this specification?
- The standard says about `RLIMIT_DATA`: “If this limit is exceeded, the malloc() function shall fail with errno set to [ENOMEM].” Does this mean that memory allocated with `malloc()` must be part of the data segment?

  On Linux, memory allocated with `mmap()` does not count towards the data segment. Only memory allocated with `brk()` or `sbrk()` is part of the data segment. Recent versions of the glibc use a `malloc()` implementation that allocates all its memory with `mmap()`. The value of `RLIMIT_DATA` thus has no effect on the amount of memory you can allocate with this implementation of `malloc()`.
- Is this a violation of POSIX.1 2008?
- Do other platforms exhibit similar behavior?

  The standard says about `RLIMIT_AS`: "If this limit is exceeded, the malloc() and mmap() functions shall fail with errno set to [ENOMEM]." As the failure of `mmap()` is not specified for `RLIMIT_DATA`, I conclude that memory obtained from `mmap()` does not count towards the data segment.
- Is this assumption true? Does this only apply to non-POSIX variants of `mmap()`?

Answer (score 4):

FreeBSD also shares the problem of malloc(3) being implemented using mmap(2) in the default malloc implementation.  I ran into this when porting a product from FreeBSD 6 to 7, where the switch happened.  We switched the default limit for each process from RLIMIT_DATA=512M to RLIMIT_VMEM=512M, i.e. limit the virtual memory allocation to 512MB.

As for whether this violates POSIX, I don't know.  My gut feeling is that lots of things violate POSIX and a 100% POSIX compliant system is as rare as a strictly-confirming C compiler.

EDIT: heh, and now I see that FreeBSD's name RLIMIT_VMEM is non-standard; they define RLIMIT_AS as RLIMIT_VMEM for POSIX compatibility.

Comment: That's sad to hear. Notice that RLIMIT_VMEM will also affect mmap()-ed files that don't consume RAM. On a 64-bit machine, you could mmap() a multiple-terabyte file without issues and it wouldn't even consume much RAM (especially if the file is sparse). So there's no method today to effectively limit the amount of real memory a process consumes...